# vapor 4.89.0 config con sqlpostgres en Xcode con swift

Tags: swift

al poner el código import Vapor

```php
import Fluent
import FluentPostgresDriver
import Leaf

public func configure(_ app: Application) throws {
    app.middleware.use(FileMiddleware(publicDirectory: app.directory.publicDirectory))
    app.views.use(.leaf)

    if let databaseURL = Environment.get("DATABASE_URL"), let url = URL(string: databaseURL) {
        app.databases.use(try! .postgres(url: url), as: .psql)
    } else {
        var config = SQLPostgresConfiguration(hostname: Environment.get("DATABASE_HOST") ?? "localhost",
                                              username: Environment.get("DATABASE_USERNAME") ?? "postgres",
                                              password: Environment.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD") ?? "password",
                                              database: Environment.get("DATABASE_NAME") ?? "database", tls: PostgresConnection.Configuration.TLS)
        
        app.databases.use(.postgres(configuration: config), as: .psql)
    }

    app.migrations.add(CreateUser())
    try routes(app)
}
```

utilizando `SQLPostgresConfiguration` ya que me dice que `PostgresConfiguration` is deprecated, me pide que ponga `TLS` pero al ponerlo me da error, y no soy capaz de salir del bucle de errores.

Comment: Qué versión de `PostgresKit` está en el proyecto?

Comment: no me aparece en mi Package.swift

Comment: dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.89.0"),
        //  An ORM for SQL and NoSQL databases.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.8.0"),
        //  Fluent driver for Postgres.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-postgres-driver.git", from: "2.7.2"),
    ],

Comment: targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "App",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Fluent", package: "fluent"),
                .product(name: "FluentPostgresDriver", package: "fluent-postgres-driver"),
                .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor"),
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: [
            .target(name: "App"),
            .product(name: "XCTVapor", package: "vapor"),

            ,

Comment: / Workaround for https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/issues/6940
            .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor"),
            .product(name: "Fluent", package: "Fluent"),
            .product(name: "FluentPostgresDriver", package: "fluent-postgres-driver")

Comment: // swift-tools-version:5.9
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "gregor",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v13)
    ],

Comment: if let databaseURL = Environment.get("DATABASE_URL") {
        let config = try SQLPostgresConfiguration(url: databaseURL)
        app.databases.use(.postgres(configuration: config.coreConfiguration), as: .psql)  error: Cannot convert value of type 'PostgresConnection.Configuration' to expected argument type 'SQLPostgresConfiguration'